# How to get URI from which REST API (ServiceStack) being consumed

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, rest, servicestack

I have some issue regarding REST API which i have built using servicestack. End user will consume this API from their application hosted on their server. I'd like to grab absolute uri and IP address from which this REST API being consumed.

When i am doing testing it locally as per below then it gives me URL of REST API itself instead of application from where it is consuming.

```
 string str = RequestContext.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
```

Please how can i get details about source from where my REST API is consuming.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand this question correctly, do you want the referrer url? or physical location path? Either way the Original ASP.NET request object should have all the information you need which you can access in your webservice with:

```
var aspnetReq = (HttpRequest)RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().OriginalRequest;
```

Which you can use to access all information about the request.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. basically i am consuming REST from web application with URL http://localhost:55531 and REST is running under http://localhost:49698/ URL. Using above code i am expecting  http://localhost:55531 but it gives me  http://localhost:49698/. Hope that you can get my point also if not then tell me i can put some screen snaps so you can understand my problem.

Comment: So you mean the Referrer Url? it will be available on aspnetReq as well.

Comment: Yes. Can i access it by  HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostName? I have tried above code but there is not property called OriginalRequest.

Comment: Yes there is: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/ServiceHost/IHttpRequest.cs#L18 and UrlReferrer is what you want: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx

Comment: UrlReferrer is null please check my updated question with more details @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612295/how-to-get-dns-name-from-rest-service-which-is-consumed-by-startuptask-of-azure

Comment: Then the client hasn't set that HTTP Header. I honestly don't know what you are looking for, check the ASP.NET request object for what you need because it is the only place that has everything. Otherwise make sure what you're looking for is on the Raw HTTP Request using Fiddler or WireShark - if its not then what you're looking for doesn't exist on the request.

Comment: I am consuming this REST service through exe which resides on web application that's why this happened! Anyway thanks for your help